# How to inverse $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: inverse-function

I have tried a couple of approaches to inversing it, but I really don't know any strategies or methods. I don't even know if it's possible or how to figure out if it is possible, so I'm asking how to know if you can inverse or not as well. $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{x-1}$

Comment: Have a look at the Lagrange inversion formula & also the Lambert $W$ function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: There is a [Lambert W](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+x%5E%281%2F%28x-1%29%29) solution. You can also use its $k$th branch for complex solutions